# Hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character OpenXML SDK

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, arrays, openxml-sdk, memorystream

I have the following function that takes a datatable and builds an Excel Spreadsheet with the data using the OpenXML SDK, and returns it as a byte array. Nine out of ten times, it works great, but occasionally, it will error out with the following message:

```
'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.
```

Here is my function:

```
Private Function buildExcelSheet(ByRef tbl As DataTable) As Byte()
        Dim memstream As New MemoryStream
        memstream.Position = 0
        Dim spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument = spreadsheetDocument.Create(memStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)

        ' Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        Dim workbookpart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart
        Try
            workbookpart.Workbook = New Workbook
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try


        ' Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
        Try
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = New Worksheet(New SheetData())
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

        ' Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Dim sheets As Sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(Of Sheets)(New Sheets())

        ' Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Dim sheet As Sheet = New Sheet
        Try
            Sheet.Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart)
            Sheet.SheetId = 1
            Sheet.Name = "Data"

            sheets.Append(Sheet)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Dim sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()
        Try
            For i As Integer = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim row As DataRow = tbl.Rows(i)
                Dim erow As New Spreadsheet.Row
                ' loop through cols
                For j As Integer = 0 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim ecell As New Spreadsheet.Cell
                    ' ecell.DataType = Spreadsheet.CellValues.String
                    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(row(j).ToString) = False Then
                        ecell.CellValue = New Spreadsheet.CellValue(row(j).ToString)
                        ecell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.String)
                    Else
                        ecell.CellValue = New Spreadsheet.CellValue(" ")
                    End If
                    erow.AppendChild(ecell)
                Next
                sheetData.AppendChild(erow)

            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Try
            workbookpart.Workbook.Save()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Try
            ' Close the document.
            spreadsheetDocument.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
        memStream.Position = 0
        Dim bytes As Byte() = memStream.ToArray()

        memStream.Close()

        Return bytes
    End Function
```

When I check the debug output, the error is always occurring at the following line:

```
spreadsheetDocument.Close()
```

I would assume that it has something to do with the data being passed to the function, but when I look at the data, I'm not seeing any NULL characters.

It certainly could be something simple that I'm overlooking, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

Here is the Debug Output around the error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
>   Compliance.dll!Compliance.Excel.buildExcelSheet(System.Data.DataTable tbl) Line 118 Basic
    Compliance.dll!Compliance.Excel.Page_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 30 + 0x13 bytes   Basic
```

Just so you all aren't missing anything, here is the caller:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim bytes As Byte()
        Try
            Call getRecords()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Problem Loading records for export to Excel: " & ex.Message)
        End Try

        Try
            bytes = buildExcelSheet(tbl)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Problem building Excel Spreadsheet: " & ex.Message)
        End Try


        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}_{1}.xlsx", focustype, rectype))
        Try
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Response.End()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post a copy of the error, including stacktrace?

Comment: This just looks like a side-effect of catch-em-all exception handling.  The web server tried to stop the page request but you won't let him.  You catch something very nasty and pretend that nothing happened, plowing ahead with corrupt data.